# How to make a connection to a Google Drive folder using the Drive API

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I've searched a lot through the web about this topic (even on StackOverflow), but the questions I was looking at weren't able to help me, so, here it is (Although im very good at it, english is not my native language, so I'm sorry for any mistake made): (SKIP TO **EDIT**)

<del>I'm making a simple chat program in Java (self learning), and, at first, I wanted to access a file on my computer. I soon found it hard to acomplish, and decided I wanted to access a drive folder on ***MY*** account. So, I *googled* about a possible Google Drive API. And I found it!!!</del>

<del>I downloaded a copy of the API to my PC, and then i went online to know how to use the API, but the README.txt file and the youtube tutorial were not helpful at all, because i could not understand the instructions. I Looked everywhere but still didnt find an easy-to-understand answer.></del>

<del>So, im asking if any of you could provide a step-by-step tutorial on how i can accomplish my goal. Ive created projects on the API consoles, but im a bit confused on what to do with them (possibly going to delete them).</del>

**EDIT**/**REDO**:

I'm making a chat program, and I want **EVERY** copy of the program to access a folder on **my** personal Google Drive and get certain files from it, where ever the user is, and without him having to see the OAuth 2.0 Autorization screen(if this last step cant be skipped, I'll work with that too).

The problem is that, although i have checked the README.txt and the youtube tutorial, i still dont understand how to use the API in the way i want.

So, im asking if any of you could provide a step-by-step tutorial on how i can accomplish my goal, i.e, (Some code could be of great use):

1st-Do this;
2nd-Do that;
...
(n steps)-You are ready;

Thank you in advance!!

P.S.: this is my last "free" question, so if this *specific* question has been answered please comment it out.

Answer (score 0):

To start using Drive API, you may may want to follow and complete the steps given in [Java Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/java).

Then to integrate with the Drive UI, you may want to check the following references:

- [Enable the Drive Platform](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/enable-sdk) - to get started integrating with the Drive UI, you need to enable the Drive API and provide configuration details in your API project. This gives you access to the API as well as access to UI integration features.
- [Install Your App](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/install) - Google Drive lets users install an app by approving an OAuth 2.0 access request.
- [Open Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/integrate-open) -  this page describes how to integrate your app with these Drive UI features to open files stored in Google Drive

Hope that helps!

Comment: TY for spending some time looking at this question, but i have already checked the links that you provided and, although im certain they work, i would like a simpler way to solve my problem. I edited the question to _try_  to explain my problem better. Still, Thank you for the time spent.

Comment: BTW, what do you mean with integrating with the Drive UI ?